# data handling in order to plot seasonal pattern over a time series data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a time series data with date range starting from 2007-04-06 until 2018-09-14

```
df.index
DatetimeIndex(['2007-04-06', '2007-04-13', '2007-04-20', '2007-04-27',
               '2007-05-04', '2007-05-11', '2007-05-18', '2007-05-25',
               '2007-06-01', '2007-06-08',
               ...
               '2018-07-13', '2018-07-20', '2018-07-27', '2018-08-03',
               '2018-08-10', '2018-08-17', '2018-08-24', '2018-08-31',
               '2018-09-07', '2018-09-14'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=588, freq=None)
```

What i am aiming to do is just plot each year as a separate line. That is 
I have tried to cut out each year using something like below and plot each year.

```
Yr2013=znSHFEstock.loc['2013-01-01':'2013-12-31']
```

However, this doesn't plot each year in separate line instead they become 1 line. 
my problems are:

1, the x axix need to be labels without a year next to it. Could be something like Jan, Feb, Mar....Dec.

2, data alignment. This is because the number of data points for each year won't be the same. For example, there might be 20 days of data points within March 2014; however, there are 18 days in March 2015. Would that be a problem in plotting them. 
Hope i made this clear and thanks for helping

Adding a runable data here

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':pd.date_range('2003-1-1', periods=4000,freq='B'),'Pre1':np.random.randint(4500, 5000, 4000)},
                  columns=['Date','Pre1'])
df=df.set_index('Date')
```

Comment: Looks like you want to provide a [mcve] of the issue which allows to see where this approach fails.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest add a runable sample script

Answer (score 0):

Plotting separate lines for each year. More efforts needed to have proper x axis tick marks. Unfortunately, have to run now, will look later

#### Dummy data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('2003-1-1', periods=4000, freq='B'), 'Pre1': np.random.randint(4500, 5000, 4000)}, columns=['Date','Pre1'])
df=df.set_index('Date')
```

#### Code

```
df['Date']=df.index
df['Year']=df['Date'].apply(lambda x: x.year)
df['DateWOYear']=df['Date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime(4,x.month,x.day))
grouped = df.groupby('Year')
fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

for y,d in grouped:
    ax.plot(d['DateWOYear'],d['Pre1'],label=y)
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sergey.  I am trying to apply the approach you provided to my actual data but doesn't work. Apologies that i should have provide a sample data before hand. I have just edited this questions by adding a runable scripts to generate the data sample. I am new to Pandas. Would you mind helping me understand this bit here: datetime.datetime(4,x.month,x.day)

Comment: @W_YY datetime.datetime(4, x.month, x.year) in a new column is to have a column where actual years replaced with year 4, first leap year (to avoid issues in case of 29th feb in the dataset). I’m also not an expert and still learning

Comment: The code now works with your data. The only change required was to replace [0] with [‘Pre1’]

Comment: I am using matplotlib 2.2.0 and i am keeping on get this msg: 
  MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance.  In a future version, a new instance will always be created and returned.  Meanwhile, this warning can be suppressed, and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance.
  warnings.warn(message, mplDeprecation, stacklevel=1)